# Microservice project throws class not found on mvn package for classes present in commn-service

Tags: java, spring-boot, build, microservices, dependency-management

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.microservice.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>wallet-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>wallet-service</name>
    <description>Wallet microservices</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
        <jackson.version>2.9.0.pr3</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microservice.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-service</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have created a project that is common-service and my every other projects uses classes from this project and it works fine but when create build of projects which uses common-service it throws *classnotfoundexception* for the classes which are present in common-service.

```
I have added dependency of common-service in other projects and added this project on build path also.
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the pom of common-service. Is it of packaging type jar? Please ensure there is a `<packaging>jar</packaging>` in the other pom coordinates.

The dependencyManagement tag above is closed, but there is no opening.

Comment: No, it didn't work, I have added the packaging also.